# eBay Web Service Error on ReviseItem - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid Padding length: 175

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, ebay-api

I am using ColdFusion to call the eBay Web Service API. Below is my code to call the Web Service via ColdFusion:

```
<cfinvoke webservice="#ebayWS#" method="#methodToCall#" refreshWSDL="yes" timeout="120" returnvariable="result">
    <cfinvokeargument name="reviseItemRequest" value="#reviseItem#">
</cfinvoke>
```

I am getting the error below:

```
Root Cause:

DETAIL: The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:

AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid Padding length: 175
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
Invalid Padding length: 175
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:974)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:190)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:403)
    ... ''

ERROR CODE:
MESSAGE: Cannot perform web service invocation reviseItem.
TYPE: Application
```

Comment: What version of Lucee/Railo/ACF are you using? I had a similar problem with PayPal's API, and I had to update my JRE's 'cacerts' entry...

Comment: Check EBay's API notifications section to see if they have recently updated their root certificate.